# Get the first occurrence by date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in SQL Server like below:

```
DECLARE @ProposalTemp AS TABLE (Flag1 BIT, Flag2 BIT, Eff_From DATE)

INSERT INTO @ProposalTemp VALUES
(0, 0,  '2019-03-01'), 
(1, 0,  '2019-03-01') ,
(0, 0, '2019-03-03') ,
(1, 1,  '2019-03-05') ,
(1, 0, '2019-03-07') ,
(1, 1, '2019-03-09');
```

Example: from table Flag1 is "1" from 05/Mar/2019 on wards. Flag2 is "1" from 09/Mar/2019 on wards.

I would like to get dates when changed to active(1) and did not change to '0' back for both columns (flag1 , flag2)

Desired output is

```
Flag1_Efff_Date    Flag2_Efff_Date
   '2019-03-05'         '2019-03-09'
```

Here another example

```
INSERT INTO @ProposalTemp VALUES 
(0, 0, '2019-03-01'), 
(1, 0, '2019-03-01') , 
(0, 0, '2019-03-03') , 
(1, 1, '2019-03-05') , 
(1, 1, '2019-03-07') , 
(1, 1, '2019-03-09');
```

And desired output would be

```
   Flag1_Efff_Date    Flag2_Efff_Date
   '2019-03-05'         '2019-03-05'
```

I have tried little bit .. Still dont know how to write this logic.

```
SELECT 
    Flag1, Flag2, Eff_From
FROM   
    (SELECT  
         Flag1, Flag2, Eff_From,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Flag1, Flag2 ORDER BY Eff_From) rn
     FROM  
         @ProposalTemp) t
WHERE  
    rn = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean `I would like to get result "05/Mar/2019" for Flag1 & "09/Mar/2019" for Flag2.`?

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: Please explain the logic for getting `05/Mar/2019` for `Flag1` and `09/Mar/2019` for `Flag2`

Comment: Desired output is   column( Flag1_Efff_Date) --> 2019-03-05'   , column( Flag2_Efff_Date) -->'2019-03-09'

Comment: @D-Shih : please check description now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess as you have not provided the required logic.

Based on the description, and expected result, looks like you wanted the 2nd instance the flag is 1

```
SELECT Flag1Date    = max(case when Flag1 = 1 and r1 = 2 then Eff_From end),
       Flag2Date    = max(case when Flag2 = 1 and r2 = 2 then Eff_From end)
FROM   
(      SELECT   Flag1,Flag2,Eff_From,
                Row_number() OVER(Partition BY Flag1 ORDER BY Eff_From ) r1,
                Row_number() OVER(Partition BY Flag2 ORDER BY Eff_From ) r2
       FROM     @ProposalTemp
) t
```

EDIT :  based on your updated question

```
; with cte as
(
    SELECT  Flag1,Flag2,Eff_From,
            Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Eff_From ) rn
    FROM    @ProposalTemp
),
f1 as
(
    select  min(Eff_From) as Flag1Date
    from    cte f1
    where   f1.Flag1    = 1
    and not exists (select * from cte x where x.Flag1 <> 1 and x.rn > f1.rn)
),
f2 as
(
    select  min(Eff_From) as Flag2Date
    from    cte f2
    where   f2.Flag2    = 1
    and not exists (select * from cte x where x.Flag2 <> 1 and x.rn > f2.rn)
)
select  *
from    f1 cross join f2
```

Comment: Hi..Thank you for response..</b> I would like to get dates when changed to active(1) and did not change to '0' back for both columns (flag1 , flag2). </b> . Here another example  <pre> INSERT INTO @ProposalTemp VALUES (0, 0, '2019-03-01'), (1, 0, '2019-03-01') , (0, 0, '2019-03-03') , (1, 1, '2019-03-05') , (1, 1, '2019-03-07') , (1, 1, '2019-03-09'); </pre>    and desired output would be Flag1Date Flag2Date
2019-03-05 2019-03-05

Comment: please update your original question with these information

Comment: Working updated solution and thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
    GO
    ;with cte as (
    select row_number() over (order by eff_from) as Slno, * from @ProposalTemp )
    , ctflg1 as (
    select * from cte where slno = (select max(slno)+1 from cte where Flag1=0))
    , ctflg2 as (
    select * from cte where slno = (select max(slno)+1 from cte where Flag2=0))
    select Flag1, Flag2, Eff_From from ctflg1
    union
    select Flag1, Flag2, Eff_From from ctflg2
    GO
```

First find out individual value for flag1 and flag2 using `cte` then use it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Below uses [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions to get your desired results.

```
DECLARE @ProposalTemp AS TABLE (Flag1 BIT, Flag2 BIT, Eff_From DATE)

INSERT INTO @ProposalTemp VALUES
(0, 0,  '2019-03-01'), 
(1, 0,  '2019-03-01') ,
(0, 0, '2019-03-03') ,
(1, 1,  '2019-03-05') ,
(1, 0, '2019-03-07') ,
(1, 1, '2019-03-09'); 

; WITH CTE_flag1flow as
(
select lag(flag1,1,null) over(order by Eff_From desc) as nex, flag1 as curr, lead(flag1,1,null) over(order by Eff_From desc) as prev, Eff_From
FROM @ProposalTemp),
CTE_flag2flow as
(
select lag(flag2,1,null) over(order by Eff_From desc) as nex, flag2 as curr, lead(flag2,1,null) over(order by Eff_From desc) as prev, Eff_From
FROM @ProposalTemp)
select * 
from 
(SELECT max(Eff_from) AS Eff_Flag1
FROM CTE_flag1Flow
WHERE curr = 1 AND prev = 0 ) AS c1
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT max(Eff_from) AS Eff_Flag2
FROM CTE_flag2Flow
WHERE curr = 1 AND prev = 0 ) AS C2
```